# How to convert Laravel DB data into a suitable JSON form to use it in vuejs

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, object, naming-conventions

The attributes of laravel modal are named using underscore (_), for example :

```
first_name
```

but attributes of javascript objects are named with camelCase:

```
{ firstName: "..." }
```

And this presents a conflict, is there a solution to resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Laravel eloquent resource pattern will do that for You.
Check this helpful documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources

Comment: Thanks. Can that affects performance of response ?

Comment: No, Will not affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

Like Zrelli Mjdi mentioned it's done with [Resource Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources#resource-collections).

I did not find a way to let this resources transform the result recursively for nested JSON-Objects, so I created a middleware (see the [github-gist](https://gist.github.com/JackLeEmmerdeur/a47d582923e933dae5cc4deb6938a1fb)) for this, which should take a rather heavy toll on performance. So use it sparsely.

I'd use this middleware only temporary if your frontend demands camel-case properties. In the long run I'd modify my migrations to use camel-case fieldnames. This should, according to [this reddit-thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/dd8l90/using_snake_case_database_fields_is_making/), be possible and won't affect performance like my middleware.

Edit: The code in the gist had a bug which is now fixed.

This is about how it's done with Resource-Collections and non-nested JSON-Results:

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Resources;
 
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
 
class MyResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'userId' => $this->user_id,
            'createdAt' => $this->created_at,
        ];
    }
}
```

in the controller:

```
public function myControllerMethod(Request $request)
{
    // ...
    return MyResource::collection($logs)
}
```